# Web bot in C++/PHP

Tags: php, c++, robots.txt, bots

I've recently started learning PHP, but I have a wide knowledge on C++. I've been wondering how to make a web bot and now, I would greatly like to make one. I won't be using this robot for spamming or anything, just as a test of what PHP/C++ can do online. I was wondering how I could go about doing this and if you have any articles/tutorials that would be helpful.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

The absolutely BEST way to get a fast introduction to Web Bots is to read Michael Schrenk's book "Webbots, Spiders and Screen Scrapers". It is a complete introduction to writing this stuff in PHP/Curl, and it is one of the best written and easiest to read CS books I have ever encountered. Code is downloadable on a companion web site. I'm reading this now and absolutely love it.

Here's the site: http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/. Since the book is from 2007 you can probably even get this ordered through a library. It's also available in a Kindle version.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following

- [PHP Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)
- [cURL in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Hint: On larger execution times, you might want to look into [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Could I please have more information? This just isn't enough!

I'll check into them though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use Python, way better than C++ when it comes to developing applications like the one you're trying to achieve. Remember that web bot/crawlers are I/O bound, not CPU bound, so the performance difference between a language like C/C++ against Python would be almost none.